# How to For loop for every 50th number start to end point in PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I want For loop to get every 50th number whenever we click next or previous it will get 50+ or 50-

Here's my code

```
<?php
$startpage=1;
$endpage=3;
for($p=$startpage;$p<=$endpage;$p++)
    {
echo file_get_html("mysite.com/mypage.php?offset=$p"); // shows offset=1, offset=2, offset=3
    }

//But I want to get offset for 50+ or 50- when click next or previous button

$startpage=0;
$endpage=200;
for($p=$startpage;$p<=$endpage;$p++)
    {
echo file_get_html("mysite.com/mypage.php?offset=$p"); // it will work like offset=0, offset=50, offset=100, offset=150, offset=200
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what the "it will work like" comment means.

Comment: The one Answer here (as of commenting now) is correct - but in general, even though this focuses on PHP, this question touches on the general idea of "loop guard" that is common to most languages in general.  Learning more about loop guards in general sounds like it would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$p+=50` instead of `$p++`

```
  for($p=$startpage;$p<=$endpage;$p+=50)
        {
    echo file_get_html("mysite.com/mypage.php?offset=$p"); // it will work like offset=0, offset=50, offset=100, offset=150, offset=200
        }
```

Comment: All additionally just add, if you need to know which page is actually a multiple of 50, use can always check with (pageNumber % 50 == 0)

Comment: @awsmsce Correct, but iterating only on multiple values of 50 is a better option than to check for each number using `%` with an increment step of  `1`.

Comment: :thumbs up: @vivek_23

Comment: @Ken you should "Accept" this Answer since you commented it "works great" (and then it will get the green checkmark making it more clear that this Answer works).  Glad you got your answer.